The tags on the stackexchange.com/tour should not be clickable
Related: Tag popup is obscured on the Tour page
Go to Stack Exchange tour page.
Click the tags shown (the unicorn and the daisies tag) in the tour page.



Links to broken page.



The bug is simple, the tags should be just displayed on the tour, but the tags should not be clickable on the tour page.

I think they should remain clickable, because they are also clickable everywhere else. Making them not clickable would lead to the potential assumption that they can't be interacted with at all on the normal site.

@Lino broken link is worse. Note that unlike in the real questions, the title of the example questions is not clickable in the Tour page, and it's clear that it's just an example and not a real question, and same for the tags.

@ShadowWizard I can’t find the duplicate question as I search in this way: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tour+tags And that time, the OP of the duplicate question used the [tag:unicorns] tag…

Ah, I searched for [stackexchange.com] broken tags is:q to find it. But yeah, it should also have the [tag:tags] tag, I agree.
